# SBT not finding snapshot version in local maven repository

Tags: maven, sbt

I recently upgraded a project from SBT 0.13 to 1.8. Now I noticed that if I publish an external project as SNAPSHOT to my local maven repository I cannot load that dependency from the directory.
Checking SBT output I found this line:

```
[error]   not found: /home/user/.m2/repository/com/example/my-service/maven-metadata.xml
```

And looking into this directory I found a file named `maven-metadata-local.xml`.

So it looks like the resolver is just not checking for the correct file. Is there a way to configure SBT to also check for `maven-metadata-local.xml` for local snapshot versions?